# Is it possible to create a npm library that does not compile the code?

Tags: reactjs, sass, vite

So I generally work with react and sass to create my front-end projects. It has come to the point that I have my own "ui" lib that is pretty tested and suits my needs perfectly. It includes the basics like controlled inputs, models, tooltips etc.
Now I have considered turning it into a module that I deploy to npm and then import in projects rather then copy pasting the files directly. However I have a problem.
My components use styling done through sass, and multi-theming through a technique I learnt online [here](https://medium.com/reactbrasil/temas-din%C3%A2micos-no-react-com-sass-7779a99d3c2f). Now for me to be able to change the theme in my components in the projects that use the lib I need the SASS to be uncompiled. Is this possible?
Im using vite to create the lib.